# MySQL query with LIMIT in a descending order doesn't work with inner joint tables

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, inner-join, sql-limit

So I have two tables that look like this:

table **follows**:

```
follower   |   following
-----------+-------------
1          |   2
-----------+-------------
1          |   3
-----------+-------------
2          |   1
-----------+-------------
1          |   4         
-----------+-------------
```

(this is basically the table that contains which user follows which user on the site...the numbers are the user id-s)

table **articles**:

```
id    |    title    |   writer
------+-------------+---------
1     |    a test   |   2      
------+-------------+---------
2     |    testing  |   3     
------+-------------+---------
3     |    another  |   2     
------+-------------+---------
4     |    again    |   4
------+-------------+---------
```

(`id` is an auto-increment field.. `title` contains the article's title.. `writer` contains the id of the user who wrote it)

Now I have a mysql **query** that looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM follows f INNER JOIN articles a ON f.following = a.writer WHERE f.follower = 1 ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 4, 2;`

But I don't get any results
**I would like to get those 2 articles out from the table that have an `id` that is SMALLER than 4. That is why I tried to put a `DESC` before `LIMIT`.**

(So I want to get the articles that have the `id` 2 and 3.)

But it doesn't work. How could I do this? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You didn't get any result because your query is returning exactly 4 rows, but your `LIMIT 4, 2` is set to skip first 4 rows and then return first 2 rows.

Comment: You said you want those 2 articles with `id` less than 4, but there are 3 articles with `id` less then 4.
What exactly do you want to get? List of all articles written by author that is user following? Last two articles?

Comment: Last two articles written by the people 'I' follow (I am userid = 1)

Comment: Then why does the result `ID`s have to be smaller than 4? You don't have `date` column in your article table, so if you want last two articles, I guess it would be articles with 2 biggest `ID`s (that are 4 and 3). Check my answer and comment it if is working.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to get those 2 articles out from the table that have an
>   id that is SMALLER than 4

Then try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM follows f 
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT *
     FROM articles
     WHERE id > 1 
        OR id < 4
) a ON f.following = a.writer
WHERE f.follower = 1
ORDER BY a.id
```

**Or:**

```
SELECT *
FROM follows f 
INNER JOIN articles a ON f.following = a.writer
WHERE f.follower = 1 
  AND (a.id > 1 OR a.id < 4 )

ORDER BY a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You are wrongly using `LIMIT` in your query. Your query returns **4 rows** with all the articles written by authors you are following ordered by article.id desceding. But your `LIMIT 4, 2` is skipping first 4 rows and then returning first 2 rows. As there are only 4 rows found, your result is empty.

Your result is ordered rightly, so if you want **last two articles**, you need to **select first two rows**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  test_follows f INNER JOIN test_articles a ON f.following = a.writer 
WHERE 
  f.follower = 1
ORDER BY 
  a.id DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is wat you want.. try this out.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follows f INNER JOIN articles a ON f.following = a.writer WHERE f.follower = 1  and a.id < 4 ORDER BY a.id ");
```

if get the articles. id smaller(lesser) than 4
hope this helps.